# How many Shiva Sahasranama is there in Mahabharata, Purana, Agama, Tantra?

Tags: scripture, shiva, shaivism, source, shiva-sahasranama

How many versions of Shiva Sahasranama is there in Mahabharata,  Purana, Agama, Tantra ? Send all with exact location...

Comment: See sanskritdocuments.org

Answer (score 1):

**Devi Bhagavatham**

Bhagiratha krutham - from devi bhagavata

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasranAmastotradevIbhAgavata.html

---

**Vayu Puranam**

Vayu Purana (1.30.179-284) is almost the same as the Mahabharata Śāntiparvan version. from vayupurana

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasranAmastotravAyupurANa.html

---

**Shiva Puranam**

Shivapurana 4.35.1-131. kotirudrasamhita
Lord Vishnu exalts Lord Shiva

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasranAmastotrashivapurANa.html

---

**Padma Puranam**

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/vedasArashivasahasranAmastotrampadmapurANa.html

---

**Saura Puranam**

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasranAmastotrasaura.html

---

**Skanda Puranam**

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasranAmastotramskanda.html

---

**Linga Puranam**

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasralinga.html

---

**Shiva rahasya - adyaya 24**

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasranAmastotramshivarahasya24.html

---

**Shiva Rahasya - adyaya 2**

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasranAmastotramshivarahasya9p2.html

---

**Rudra Yamala**

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_shiva/shivasahasrarudrayAmala.html

---

**Mahabharata Anushāsanaparva**

Krishna states the thousand names of Shiva to Yudhishthira in the 17th chapter of Anushāsanaparva

---

**Mahabharata  Shanti parva**

> Mahabharata (Shanti Parva), Chapter 284 (Gita Press edition]]) also has a Shiva Sahasranama sung by Daksha to please Lord Rudra. This is not present in its complete from in the Critical Edition. This is also accepted by Traditional scholars.(credit sWikipedia)

*PS - credits/courtesy sanskritdocuments.org*

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the references given, [The Brahma Purana also contains a Shiva sahasranama](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/brahma%20purana.html).

[A devanagari rendition present here](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D/%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_%E0%A5%AA%E0%A5%A6)

The Devi Mahabhagavata purana (different from Devi Bhagavata) also has a Shiva sahasranama as available [here](https://archive.org/details/kalyan-79-1-devi-puran-mahabhagavat-shakti-pithank-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n368/mode/1up?view=theater)