What is the correct shiva Sahasranama?
Can anyone provide the right shiva Sahasranama . I am getting multiple different results which donot match , at various websites in the Internet. How many variations are there for the shiva Sahasranama ?

It is not necessary that there will be one .. Various scriptures contain various Sahasranam stotrams .. for example this page (https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/shiva%20purana.html) gives four such stotras found in Linga Purana, Shiva Purana,Brahma Purana and the Mahabharata.

There is an youtube video by “The Sanskrit Channel“, check it.

All the versions found in the scriptures are correct. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58776/34973
